# Where in the WordPress database are registered custom post types saved?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In WordPress, after a custom post type has been registered, but before it has been associated with a post, it is available through the global variable `$wp_post_types`. The function `post_type_exists()` can be used to check if a particular type exists in that variable.

My question is, where in the WordPress database are custom post types saved before they are associated with a post? The documentation seems to suggest that they are saved in the `wp_posts` table, but that table associates posts with types - it doesn't store types that have no posts.

Comment: The question was put on hold for being 'too broad'. It was a two part question. One part (how to access registered custom posts types outside of the loop) has been answered, the second part could be answered in two words - table name, field name. I'm not sure how this is too broad. If it had been flagged as being lazy I would understand.

Comment: I see now that they don't exist in the database at all until they are associated with a post. A custom post type is registered  in a file that is required through a plugin or a theme. Registering the custom post type assigns it to the $wp_post_types global variable. When a post is created that uses a particular custom post type it is then entered into the WordPress database in the type field of the wp_posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a custom post type you will see in the sidebar in the dashboard, once you create at least one post, you can check for that post's `post_type` column in the `wp_post` table

You can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)

Besides, you can use some functions to check if a post type is registered.

[get_post_types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types)

[post_type_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_exists)

Comment: post_type_exists is what I was looking for!